# Does the order of differentiation matter for the cumulative density function of a multivariate random variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, random-variables, hessian-matrix

consider $F(x,y) = P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)$. Does $\frac{d^2F}{dxdy} = \frac{d^2F}{dydx}$? Also the symmetry means the hessian exists right? What would be the meaning behind such symmetry?

Comment: If a function is twice differentiable, then its mixed partial derivatives of second order coincide. In symbols, if $F:\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$ is twice differentiable at $p,$ then $\partial^2_{x,y} F(p) = \partial^2_{y,x} F(p).$ The reciprocal result is known to be false, that is to say, there are functions whose second partial derivatives exist at a point, the mixed partial coincide there and the function is not twice differentiable. I suspect that if a distribution function in $\mathbf{R}^2$ admits a density of class $\mathsf{C}^k,$ then it is at least $k+1$ times differentiable...

Comment: ...Of course, the result should be much better (I just don't know any) as in if the density is continuous, then $F:\mathbf{R}^2 \to \mathbf{R}$ is already twice differentiable almost everywhere and, therefore, the mixed partials differ at most on a zero-measure set, so the order in which you take them is immaterial.

Comment: Actually, after thinking a bit more, this result is generally true, whether or not $F$ is any differentiable. By definition, $F(x,y) = \int_{(-\infty, x] \times (-\infty, y]} f$ (where $f$ is a density for $F$). Assume $f$ is continuous as in the vast majority of applications. Then, Tonelli's theorem show that the expression for $F$ can be written as $\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f = \int_{-\infty}^y \int_{-\infty}^x f.$ Then, $\partial_y \partial_x F = f(x,y)$ using the expression on the left and $\partial_x \partial_y F = f(x,y)$ using the one on the right.